# Matplotlib.pyplot scatter: Setting ylim min to zero not working

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have extracted some table data using the code below:

```
import pandas as pd  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

stat_dict={'Disposals' : 0,
           'Kicks' : 1,
           'Marks' : 2,
           'Handballs' : 3,
           'Goals' : 4,
           'Behinds' : 5,
           'Hitouts' : 6,
           'Tackles' : 7,
           'Rebounds' : 8,
           'Inside50s' : 9,
           'Clearances': 9,
           'Clangers' : 10,
           'FreesFor' : 11,
           'FreesAgainst' : 12,
           'ContestedPosessions' : 13,
           'UncontestedPosesseions' : 14,
           'ContestedMarks' : 15,
           'MarksInside50' : 16,
           'OnePercenters' : 17,
           'Bounces' : 18,
           'GoalAssists' : 19,
           'Timeplayed' : 20}

team_lower_case='fremantle'
player="Fyfe, Nat"
stat_required='Disposals'
rounds=7

tables = pd.read_html("https://afltables.com/afl/stats/teams/" 
+str(team_lower_case)+"/2018_gbg.html")

for df in tables:
    df.drop(df.columns[rounds+1:], axis=1, inplace=True)   # remove 
unwanted columns
    df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)    # remove extra index level

stat_table=tables[stat_dict[stat_required]]

player_stat=stat_table[stat_table["Player"]==player]
player_stat=player_stat.iloc[:,1:8]
```

Which outputs this:

```
     R1    R2    R3    R4    R5    R6    R7
8  22.0  29.0  38.0  25.0  43.0  27.0  33.0
```

I then plot this data:

```
plt.scatter(range(1,rounds+1),player_stat)
plt.show()
```

￼[image]
I want to set the y axis limit to zero:

```
plt.ylim(0,50)
```

But it results in the plot being all squashed and weird:
[image]

I've tried the following as well:

```
plt.ylim(ymin=0)
```

[image]

Comment: When I use `y = [22.0, 29.0, 38.0, 25.0, 43.0, 27.0, 33.0]; 
plt.scatter(range(len(y)),y); plt.ylim(0,50)` - It works for me (NOT all scrunched up).  What version are you using?

Comment: What is the type and dtype of `player_stat`?

Comment: @wwii I tried your code and indeed it worked as expected. Maybe I'm having a problem with the data itself? I'm using Python 3.6

Comment: @xg.plt.py player_stat is a pandas DataFrame. I'm not sure what you mean by dtype?

Comment: It looks like your data are strings. You may want to convert them to integers

Answer (score 2):

Your data are *strings*. The problem can be reproduced using the following:

```
y = ["22.0", "29.0", "38.0", "25.0", "43.0", "27.0", "33.0"]
plt.scatter(range(len(y)),y)
plt.ylim(0,50)
```

[image]

You need to convert `player_stat` to a numeric data type. One possible way to do this would be using `.astype(float)`. For your example it would be something like:

```
plt.scatter(range(1,rounds+1), player_stat.astype(float))
```

Comment: I agree that the data are strings, but following your suggestion didn't work either. The result is the same as the third example of my post.